# pyplot colorbar not showing precise values

Tags: python, matplotlib, precision, colorbar

I have a contour map with a colorbar. However, it truncates a few significant digits, and just show the rest of the digits on the side.[image]

Is there a way to more precisely display the significant digits on the colorbar (i.e., labels with more significant digits)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`format` argument](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar) of colorbar to set your own output format of colorbar labels like in this example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# specify your own
# formatter for colorbar labels
# in return select desired format
def myfmt(x, pos):
    return '{0:.5f}'.format(x)

# test data
arr = np.random.randn(111,111) * 1.e-2
cf = plt.contourf(arr)

# apply formatter for colorbar labels
plt.colorbar(cf, format=ticker.FuncFormatter(myfmt))
plt.show()
```

If your formatter function is simple you have to write just like here

```
plt.colorbar(cf, format='%.5f')
```

[image]